# How does asterisk affect expressions in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm confused about why does asterisk have an impact on the regular expressions results in Ruby? Example codes are below:

```
2.3.0 :001 > "abbcccddddeeeee"[/z*/]
 => "" 
2.3.0 :002 > "abbcccddddeeeee"[/z/]
 => nil
```

Why the first one with `*` returns an empty string, while the other one returns `nil`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a quantifier that means "0 or more".

Your first snippet matches 0 instance of `z`. Your second snippet doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Kleene star means "zero or more". In the first case, there are 0 `z`s in the string, which means that there is a match (actually even infinitely many matches) of "zero or more `z`s".

In the second case, you search for the occurrence of a single `z` in the string which doesn't exist.